# If taxonomy vocabulary changes from Translate to Localize how to combine terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

My d7 is using i18n, internationalization taxonomy. I have vocabulary that have option Translate. So it looks like (eng, de):
Creative
- Projects
- Portfolio
Kreativ (de)
- Projekte (de)
- Portfolio (de)

These terms have relations between one and other. Really I have about 150 terms and  want to simplify this vocabulary. Need to change it to Localize option. If I will check Localize all terms beacame independent (single) so this is very very bad.
How to combine all of them, please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should consider using the [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module. From its project page:

> ... provides a powerful interface for managing taxonomies. A vocabulary gets displayed in a dynamic tree view, where parent terms can be expanded to list their nested child terms or can be collapsed.
>
> The Taxonomy Manager has following operations and key features:
>
> - ...
> - merging of terms (using the [Term merge](http://drupal.org/project/term_merge) module in 7.x)
> - ...